# Как вызвать диалог выбора пути к папке в Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, dialog

Нужно добавить возможность выбора пути к папке в Delphi. Как вызвать стандартный системный диалог?

Comment: SelectDirectory ?

Comment: Смотрите функцию `SelectDirectory`

Comment: Я пробовала но не могу в данном коде реализовать. Подскажете как ?

Comment: А зачем вы приложили столько не относящегося кода к вопросу? Уберите лишнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавила код для полной картины. Буду благодарна за помощь. Я знаю что функция простая но я начинаю только все учить.

Answer (score 4):

В Windows Vista и выше, можно использовать такой код:

```
var
  OpenDialog: TFileOpenDialog;
  SelectedFolder: string;
.....
OpenDialog := TFileOpenDialog.Create(MainForm);
try
  OpenDialog.Options := OpenDialog.Options + [fdoPickFolders];
  if not OpenDialog.Execute then
    Abort;
  SelectedFolder := OpenDialog.FileName;
finally
  OpenDialog.Free;
end;
```

Или универсальный (для XP и выше):

```
uses
  FileCtrl;
...
var
  SelectedFolder: string;
begin
  SelectDirectory('Выберите директорию','',SelectedFolder);
end;
```

Comment: Очень благодарна за подсказку. Мне еще учить и учить...

Comment: `BrowseForFolder` еще был какой-то

Comment: @Татьяна, в таком случае стоит принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.